# Scala: how to modify the default metric for cross validation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cross-validation, metrics, evaluator

I find te code below on this site:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/ml-tuning.html

```
// Note that the evaluator here is a BinaryClassificationEvaluator and its default metric
// is areaUnderROC.
val cv = new CrossValidator()
  .setEstimator(pipeline)
  .setEvaluator(new BinaryClassificationEvaluator)
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
  .setNumFolds(2)  // Use 3+ in practice
  .setParallelism(2)  // Evaluate up to 2 parameter settings in parallel
```

As they said the default metric for BinaryClassificationEvaluator is "AUC".
How can I do to change this default metric to F1-score?

I tried:

```
// Note that the evaluator here is a BinaryClassificationEvaluator and its default metric
// is areaUnderROC.
val cv = new CrossValidator()
  .setEstimator(pipeline)
  .setEvaluator(new BinaryClassificationEvaluator.setMetricName("f1"))
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
  .setNumFolds(2)  // Use 3+ in practice
  .setParallelism(2)  // Evaluate up to 2 parameter settings in parallel
```

But I got some errors...
I search on many sites but I did not find the solution...

Answer (score 0):

`setMetricName` only accepts "areaUnderPR" or "areaUnderROC". You will need to write your own `Evaluator`; something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.Evaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.shared.{HasLabelCol, HasPredictionCol}
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.Identifiable
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, functions => F}

class FScoreEvaluator(override val uid: String) extends Evaluator with HasPredictionCol with HasLabelCol{

  def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("FScoreEvaluator"))

  def evaluate(dataset: Dataset[_]): Double = {
    val truePositive = F.sum(((F.col(getLabelCol) === 1) && (F.col(getPredictionCol) === 1)).cast(IntegerType))
    val predictedPositive = F.sum((F.col(getPredictionCol) === 1).cast(IntegerType))
    val actualPositive = F.sum((F.col(getLabelCol) === 1).cast(IntegerType))

    val precision = truePositive / predictedPositive
    val recall = truePositive / actualPositive
    val fScore = F.lit(2) * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)

    dataset.select(fScore).collect()(0)(0).asInstanceOf[Double]
  }

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): Evaluator = defaultCopy(extra)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this is not working. Is it scala or pyspark...? I have some error when I run your code: "error: not found: type Evaluator", "error: not found: type HasPredictionCol", "error: not found: value F"....

Comment: @Anneso It's Scala. Did you run the `import` statements? Also, what version of Spark are you using? Sounds like < 2.3.

Comment: I am using the version 2.1.1.2.6.1.0-129 of Spark and the version 2.11.8 of scala. Yes, I did run the import statment and I did not get any error when doing it...

Comment: Yup, Spark < 2.3 has those mixins private.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your last comment. Any ideas to do that with my Spark version?

Comment: I think you'd better use Spark > 2.3. BTW, I am trying to modify this to calculate weighted RMSE. So I added `with HasWeightCol`. Then I am trying to create an evaluator object as `new myEvaluator().setLabelCol(labelColName).setPredictionCol(predColName).setWeightCol(weightColName)`. But it failed with the error `value setLabelCol is not a member of WRmseEvaluator`. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @gmds. Make sure Spark version >=2.3.

You can also follow [the implementation of RegressionEvaluator in Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/evaluation/RegressionEvaluator.scala) to implement other custom evaluators.

I also added `isLargerBetter` so that the instantiated evaluator can be used in model selection (e.g. CV)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.Evaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.shared.{HasLabelCol, HasPredictionCol, HasWeightCol}
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.Identifiable
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, functions => F}

class WRmseEvaluator(override val uid: String) extends Evaluator with HasPredictionCol with HasLabelCol with HasWeightCol {

    def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("wrmseEval"))

    def setPredictionCol(value: String): this.type = set(predictionCol, value)
    
    def setLabelCol(value: String): this.type = set(labelCol, value)
    
    def setWeightCol(value: String): this.type = set(weightCol, value)
    
    def evaluate(dataset: Dataset[_]): Double = {
        dataset
            .withColumn("residual", F.col(getLabelCol) - F.col(getPredictionCol))
            .select(
                F.sqrt(F.sum(F.col(getWeightCol) * F.pow(F.col("residual"), 2)) / F.sum(getWeightCol))
            )
            .collect()(0)(0).asInstanceOf[Double]

    }

    override def copy(extra: ParamMap): Evaluator = defaultCopy(extra)

    override def isLargerBetter: Boolean = false
}
```

The following is how to use it.

```scala
val wrmseEvaluator = new WRmseEvaluator()
    .setLabelCol(labelColName)
    .setPredictionCol(predColName)
    .setWeightCol(weightColName)
```